# How to add new web page to VSC liveserver?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cant find how to add another web page to VSC Live Server extension.
It shows me one old web page again and again if I am trying add another page.
I was searching how to fix this problem but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Add that web page inside the folder that you are viewing.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Thanks a lot

Comment: So it worked or what?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour yes, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add new webpage to your project in Visual Studio Code Live Server :

Just move your files to the folder that you are viewing in Visual Studio Code Live Server Extension.